# How do I get the current major mode?

Tags: major-mode

If I am editing a .tex file in emacs, by default (for me) the bottom right corner of the frame will say "LaTeX/P". However, I won't get to that mode by typing "M-x LaTeX/P-mode"; I can only get to it by typing "M-x latex-mode".

Other than Googling it, how am I supposed to know the thing I type to get to that mode is "latex-mode"?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to check the value of the buffer-local `major-mode` variable, with either of:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `major-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-:</kbd> `major-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: How to check if the major-mode is `org-mode` for example? `(equal major-mode "org-mode")` always return `nil` even when I'm in org-mode.

Comment: @Student That's because you're comparing two entirely different data types: `"org-mode"` is a *string*, whereas the value of `major-mode` is a *symbol*, so naturally they are not (cannot be) equal.  `(equal major-mode 'org-mode)` would be `t` in `org-mode` buffers.  *Generally* to test the current buffer's major mode you would use `(derived-mode-p 'org-mode)`, which will return non-nil not only for `org-mode` itself, but also for any mode which was *derived* from `org-mode`.

Comment: As a emacs noob, I thank you for your answer! Also for those who are new, you can use `(type-of major-mode)` to check that it's actually a symbol but not a string!

Answer (score 18):

`C-h m` gives you help on the current mode, and it typically tells you the name of the command that turns the mode on.

For example, in Emacs-Lisp mode `C-h m` tells you that you are in `Emacs-Lisp` mode. The command that turns the mode on is just `emacs-lisp-mode`.

`C-h m` also provides a link to the library that defines the mode, and if you click on that link it takes you to the definition of the mode command. For example, in Emacs-Lisp mode `C-h m` tells you:

```
Emacs-Lisp mode defined in `lisp-mode.el'
```

And if you click the link `lisp-mode.el` then Emacs takes you to the definition of command `emacs-lisp-mode`, which is the command that turns the mode on:

```el
(define-derived-mode emacs-lisp-mode prog-mode "Emacs-Lisp"
  "Major mode for editing Lisp code to run in Emacs.
  ...)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get the major mode just by evaluating this expression:

`(print major-mode)`

Comment: This seems to repeat @phils's answer: examine variable `major-mode` (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18084/105).

Comment: Yes we are evaluating the same thing variable ofcourse, since that's what stores the value of the major-mode. Difference is just how you want to implement that function. maybe we can define a function, with this command in place and bind it with a key. So my point being elisp vs using emacs mode line.